# When we get "Can't process temp ncss xml file" error?

Tags: maven, jenkins

When we get this type of error in javancss

`An error has occurred in JavaNCSS Report report generation. Can't process temp ncss xml file.`

Answer (score 0):

Changed `Goals and options` from `findbugs:findbugs javancss:report test` to `findbugs:findbugs test javancss:report` in jenkins.